# how do you rewrite a recursive formula to find its roots

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, recursive-algorithms

Let $(x_n)$ be the sequence defined by $x_1=2$ and the recursive formula $x_{n+1} = \frac12 + \sqrt{x_n}$.

Rewrite the recursive formula in the form

$$ x_n - x_{n+1} = ax_{n+1}^2 + bx_{n+1} + c$$

and find the roots of the quadratic polynomial on the right hand side.

Comment: It would be better to share your thoughts on this problem: e.g. where does it come from, what are your thoughts about solving it, how far have you got? At the moment it reads as if you are giving us a command!

Comment: I was wondering how to go about this problem as i havent encountered something like this before. Maybe i have overlooked something vital and need insight

Comment: IT's better to try some things and hit a dead end or two first. Then we kjnow how you're thinking about the problem, and how to push you in the right direction. If you have no idea how to even begin, since it says to write an equation, start by writing the left hand side in *some* way.

Comment: my initial response was the rearrange the equation to get xn alone and to solve (xn+1-1/2)^2 binomially

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* Use the recursive formula to get rid of $x_{n+1}$ in the target equation and see if you can collect matching summands, thus finding good suggestions for $a,b,c$.

Comment: I thought it would be something along those lines but i still find myself unable to understand the question